# Implementing simple symmetric encryption using java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am writing a peer to peer application and I want to implement simple symmetric encryption.

I'm looking for a good example of how to do this, I don't mind which library it uses so long as it's free.

Preferably all the encryption would happen at the socket layer so I wouldn't need to change my code at all.

Can someone provide such an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java already comes with [SSL Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html). There is no need to manually implement the encryption. The socket handles everything on its own.

Comment: To see how to write code using SSL in Java, take a look at this page: http://igorpolevoy.com/public/Wiki.jsp?page=JavaSecurity

Comment: when i think of SSL i'm thinking of needing certificates, is it possible to use SSL sockets using only a pre-shared key and no certs needed?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Java have cryptography build in... Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) & Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#ProviderArch

> The Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) extends the JCA API to include
>   APIs for encryption, key exchange, and Message Authentication Code
>   (MAC). Together, the JCE and the cryptography aspects of the SDK
>   provide a complete, platform-independent cryptography API.

Here's an example of how to use AES in Java:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html

> The JCE framework is a very powerful and flexible framework for using
>   different cryptographic algorithms. It's based on a provider
>   architecture that enables the same framework to be used for newer
>   cryptographic algorithms. From a developer perspective, this means a
>   higher level of abstraction, and a common set of APIs for newer and
>   different cryptographic algorithms -- without the need to worry about
>   the inner workings of the algorithm.
>
> Some of the other Java security APIs -- such as JSSE -- are
>   implemented on top of JCE, and supplement it to make the different
>   cryptographic algorithms (ciphers, Message Authentication Codes
>   (MACs), and Key Exchange algorithms) available to in a more
>   developer-friendly manner.

Also, as [Kristian Antonsen mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076761/196921), check out [SSLSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html).

---

Anyway, here's another Java cryptography library:

http://bouncycastle.org/java.html